# Manipulate DOM element every 10th second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

How do I manipulate an DOM element every 10th second?

I've tried like this:

```
var endurance = angular.element('.progressbar').height();
var endurance2 = angular.element('.progressbar').css('height', endurance-25);                                       

window.setInterval(foo, 10000);

foo();

function foo()
{
    console.log("Update"); //This is running
    endurance2 = angular.element('.progressbar').css('height', endurance-25); //But not this
}
```

As you can see, my console.log("update"); is running, but the element is not update.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: Because endurance is always going to be the same. You do not re-calculate it everytime..

Comment: @PSL: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`endurance` is always the same, resulting in your progressbar having always the same height. Recalculate `endurance` in your `foo` method and you should be fine:

```
function foo()
{
    console.log("Update"); //This is running
    endurance = angular.element('.progressbar').height();
    endurance2 = angular.element('.progressbar').css('height', endurance-25);
}
```

Comment: and for which case used endurance2 variable?

Comment: Ask the OP, not me :D